# Azure Application Insights Snapshot Collector throwing exception when error occurs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured and working on a on-premises .NET website. I recently added Snapshot Collector NuGet package to the site and confirmed it was configured to be used in the projects ApplicationInsights.config file, but have been unable to actually view the snapshots within Application Insights - when viewing exceptions, all it shows me is the 'Collect debug snapshots...' link as if I did not have it configured in the project.

Today I was looking at a few exceptions and noticed that Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.ProductionBreakpointsNativeMethods is throwing exceptions as well:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.ProductionBreakpointsNativeMethods' threw an exception.Could not load C:\Windows\TEMP\MinidumpUploader\ProductionBreakpoints_x64.dll

Looks like it is trying to create the snapshot on exceptions but it is just generating another exception in the processes. Any ideas what would cause the above exception? I am not sure what MiniDumpUploader is, so if that is something I am supposed to have configured on our server that may be the issue. I checked the installation instructions for Snapshot Collector and in mentions nothing of this, though.

Comment: please contact us at snapshothelp@microsoft.com and we'll try to diagnose this.

Comment: Obvious question: Have you checked to see if that DLL exists in that TEMP folder? The Snapshot Collector copies its support binaries to that location at runtime in order to avoid file locking if/when you update the site.

Comment: Just checked and that DLL does exist in that location. I will shoot a e-mail to that help address.

Comment: Patrick and I resolved this offline. There were two issues: 1. While the TEMP folder was writable, it didn't have Execute rights. 2. This was on a Windows 7 machine which, unfortunately, is not supported.